# FreeIPA Server Install with external CA

Tags: certificate-authority, lets-encrypt, freeipa

I am tasked with building a FreeIPA server to help us manage TLS certificates to support Nginx, Postgres and RabbitMQ. I have never worked with certs from an admin perspective so I may be making some assumptions that are impeding progress.

The gist of the problem is that I run *ipa-server-install* with several options including -*-external-ca*. The resulting CSR is signed by LetsEncrypt via certbot (I also tried gethttpsforfree but still get the same result). When I take the signed CSR certificate and run it through ipa-server-install with -*-external-cert-file* arguments for the signed CSR cert and fullchain.pem (as created by letsencrypt - via certbot) the result is an error.

```
CA certificate chain is incomplete: missing certificate with subject 'CN=DST Root CA X3,O=Digital Signature Trust Co.'
```

I have added LetsEncrypt as a trusted cert on the FreeIPA server so it should find the cert and trust it. According to all I have read it should be as "simple" as taking the CSR, signing it and stitching it to the existing CA chain.

What am I missing to get ipa-server-install to complete the second step?

Comment: The error suggests that the CA certificate you installed (the one that created your IPA CA certificate from your CSR) is in fact an intermediate CA, which in turn is signed by another one (`CN=DST ROOT CA X3`). You need to install that one as trusted as well.

Comment: Thank you @JamesSneeringer I do see DST ROOT CA in the trust bundle which is odd because I had considered that that the DST cert was missing from the trust.

The options I am using for the initial install process are

sudo ipa-server-install --realm MYDOMAIN.COM --domain mydomain.com --setup-dns --auto-forwarders --allow-zone-overlap --external-ca --ca-subject "CN=mydomain.com"

If seems pretty vanilla to me.

Comment: In addition to installing the upstream CA certificates as trusted, I also put the entire certificate chain in a single file and passed that to `--external-cert-file`. If you're on a RHEL-derivative (e.g., CentOS), make sure you run `update-ca-trust` after copying the CA certificates to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`.